# Como deixar uma imagem colocada pelo css responsivo.?

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Olá galera eu tô com um pequeno problema aqui, é o seguinte...

Fiz o rodapé do site tudo certinho, com largura fluida de 100% mas comecei fazer pela versão desktop e a img de fundo que eu coloquei com a mesma largura da página. Eu coloquei a img de fundo, do rodapé através do css.

Mas quando eu diminuo a tela, a DIV do rodape que contem a img diminuem,
mas a img não diminui. A cada vez que eu diminuo a tela, a minha div rodapé diminuem mais e a minha imagem não.

A img fica contida dentro do elemento pai, sem ultrapassar, mais não diminuem.

Meu codigo:

HTML

```
< footer >
Contém as redes sociais e quem somo... 
< /footer >
```

CSS

```
footer{
width:100%;
 height:250px;
Background-image url("_img/index/banner-rodapé. Jpg" ) 
Background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Amigo sem seu código não da para te ajudar, edite e inclua o código. No mais vc pode tentar colocando a largura da imagem em 100% para ver se resolve...

Comment: @hugocsl  postei o código...

Answer (score 0):

Para a imagem diminuir junto com o elemento que você aplicou a propriedade css `background-image`, você precisa aplicar no mesmo elemento a propriedade `background-size`.

#### Exemplo

```css
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2600/0*UR0r5pSLQbvP_yUo.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

#### Dica

Experimente executar o trecho de código acima sem as propriedades `background-size` e `background-position` para ver a diferença.

#### Referências

- [`background-size | MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)
- [`background-position | MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)